How to create a recursive C++ concept with a parameter pack that is called recursively
Is there a way - and if yes, how - to create a C++ concept that includes a parameter pack for the checked type and is then called recursively, such that more matches yield a better match for overloading?
Say I have,
template <typename U, typename V>
struct MyType {};

struct TypeA {};
struct TypeB {};

For which I want to have a concept:
template <typename T, typename... Args>
concept WithMyType = requires (...);

Such that I can have:
void foo(WithMyType auto);               // (1)
void foo(WithMyType<TypeA> auto);        // (2)
void foo(WithMyType<TypeA, TypeB> auto); // (3)

int main() {
  auto aa = MyType<TypeA, TypeA>();
  auto ab = MyType<TypeA, TypeB>();
  auto bb = MyType<TypeB, TypeB>();

  foo(aa); // matches (1), (2); calls (2) (better match)
  foo(ab); // matches (1), (2), (3); calls (3) (better match)
  foo(bb); // matches (1); calls (1) (only match)
}


For priority, WithMyType<TypeA, TypeB> has to subsume WithMyType<TypeA>.

AFAIK a concept is only a yes/no. There is no order of matching them. So to get an order you would have to rely on actual matching from the type (doesn't look like that's what you want), or to make the concept itself reject the less wanted types if a better match is available. If the concept is aware of the possible combinations before-hand you might have a chance of making it work.

@Jarod42 Yes, I assume it has to implemented as a concept that is called recursively, with one argument from the parameter pack peeled off in each iteration. But I don't even know where to start to get something like this to work :-/

@super I think it would only be possible by referring to another concept that can then be called with an &&. E.g., if one would hardcode it (which I don't want), one would have something like <template ...> concept WithMyType = WithMyType_<A, B> && WithMyType<A> such that each additional matching type adds another matching concept to the overall count and thus a higher specificity for overloading

@MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper: Concepts cannot recurse. Also, subsumption rules are not based on the template parameters to a concept.

I don't think about recursion, but intermediate concepts. But I have difficulty to understand your matching concept, (for me (1) would match only for MyType<> (assuming variadic template, as you already have typo 2 vs 3)...

Can you explain why WithMyType<MyType<TypeA, TypeB>, TypeA> is true? The intention is still unclear to me. I understand the desire for subsumption, what I don't yet understand is the reasoning that overload (2) is considered a possible match for MyType<TypeA, TypeB>. What I'm looking for is an explanation that would help to extrapolate what is generally intended.

For 2) template<class T> void foo(MyType<TypeA, T>); and for 3) void foo(MyType<TypeA, TypeB>)  like this?

@TedLyngmo Wow, this looks almost perfect! Is there any way you can make the case (2) not require to specify the open template parameter T, but instead just leave it out?
Also, I think this is a great solution and should be posted as an answer!

@TedLyngmo Related to that, can you explain why this works with zero and two template arguments, but not with one? Could I augment this to also work with only the first template arg specified?

@MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper Hmm, I'm really terrible at concepts so I'm not sure how to improve it further. In the two parameter case, no concept is used in my version. It's not even a function template.

Unfortunately without P2963R1, it's hard to do this with a pack.
But for a specified number of args you can do it https://godbolt.org/z/zTPbavc95
namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    inline constexpr bool WithMyType0 = false;
    template<typename U, typename V>
    inline constexpr bool WithMyType0<MyType<U, V>> = true;
    template<typename T, typename UV>
    inline constexpr bool WithMyType1 = false;
    template<typename U, typename V, typename UV>
    inline constexpr bool WithMyType1<MyType<U, V>, UV> = std::same_as<U, UV> || std::same_as<V, UV>;
}

template<typename T>
concept WithMyType0 = detail::WithMyType0<T>;
template<typename T, typename A>
concept WithMyType1 = WithMyType0<T> && detail::WithMyType1<T, A>;
template<typename T, typename A, typename B>
concept WithMyType2 = WithMyType1<T, A> && WithMyType1<T, B>;
template<typename T, typename A, typename B, typename C>
concept WithMyType3 = WithMyType2<T, A, B> && WithMyType1<T, C>;
// ...

void foo(WithMyType0 auto);               // (1)
void foo(WithMyType1<TypeA> auto);        // (2)
void foo(WithMyType2<TypeA, TypeB> auto); // (3)

int main() {
  auto aa = MyType<TypeA, TypeA>();
  auto ab = MyType<TypeA, TypeB>();
  auto bb = MyType<TypeB, TypeB>();

  foo(aa); // matches (1), (2); calls (2) (better match)
  foo(ab); // matches (1), (2), (3); calls (3) (better match)
  foo(bb); // matches (1); calls (1) (only match)
}

The normalized form of WithMyType2<T, A, B> is the conjunction of the normalized form WithMyType1<T, A> and WithMyType<T, B>, which in turn is the conjunction of the atomic constraints detail::WithMyType0<T>, detail::WithMyType1<T, A>, detail::WithMyType0<T> and detail::WithMyType1<T, B>.
The duplicate detail::WithMyType0<T> can be entirely disregarded, but you can see how this would subsume WithMyType1<T, A>, which has normalized form of the conjunction of detail::WithMyType0<T> and detail::WithMyType1<T, A>.
